# Why I got 'The computed initial AR coefficients are not stationary' even after differencing my time series?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, arima

I wanted to know why did I got **'The computed initial AR coefficients are not stationary'** even after specifying the differencing order as 1 while using `ARIMA(1,1,1)`. The `df['prod rate']` contains values in ascending order from 1 to 20 and I am pretty sure to remove trend I need to apply 1st order differencing here.

I already went through the following answer links:

1. [Why I got 'The computed initial AR coefficients are not stationary' while using aic_min_order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453381/why-i-got-the-computed-initial-ar-coefficients-are-not-stationary-while-using)
2. [Python Statsmodel ARIMA start [stationarity]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316935/python-statsmodel-arima-start-stationarity)

But I couldn't find any solution to my problem.

```py
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
plt.figure(figsize = (10,6))
model = ARIMA(df['prod rate'], order = (1,1,1))  
results_AR = model.fit()
plt.plot(df['prod rate'], label = "Original")
plt.plot(results_AR.fittedvalues, color = 'red', label = 'Predictions')
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
```

**I got following error while fitting my model:**

```py
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-2b92bbf4a4de> in <module>()
      2 plt.figure(figsize = (10,6))
      3 model = ARIMA(df['prod rate'], order = (1,1,1))
----> 4 results_AR = model.fit()
      5 plt.plot(df['prod rate'], label = "Original")
      6 plt.plot(results_AR.fittedvalues, color = 'red', label = 'Predictions')

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/statsmodels/tsa/arima_model.py in _fit_start_params_hr(self, order, start_ar_lags)
    539         if p and not np.all(np.abs(np.roots(np.r_[1, -start_params[k:k + p]]
    540                                             )) < 1):
--> 541             raise ValueError("The computed initial AR coefficients are not "
    542                              "stationary\nYou should induce stationarity, "
    543                              "choose a different model order, or you can\n"

ValueError: The computed initial AR coefficients are not stationary
You should induce stationarity, choose a different model order, or you can
pass your own start_params.
```